# How to add sqlite for IOS in windows (React Native)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

i'm in windows and i have access just to android emulator. i'm considering developing app for both android ios using react-native.

for data persistence i wanna use sqlite3 but the point is i can't find any tutorial showing how to add this library for both platforms in windows. i mean i followed tutorials and added SQLite to android, but for IOS the tutorials says go to Xcode ,... .

whats the point of react native cross platform developing when things are divided and can't be done in one side.

so my question is now that i added Sqlite to my android , how can i add it for ios too?

for adding to android i had to go change some `Gradle` files and `MainApplication` , ... . for IOS what should i do?

Comment: Although you are creating a `react-native` application you are fundamentally creating an `Android` and an `iOS` application. So you won't find any tutorials showing you how to edit native `iOS` code on a Windows machine as you can only develop `iOS` applications on a Mac.

Comment: @Andrew so how should i add sqlite in windows for ios devices. all tutorials are saying sth that is only available in mac.

Comment: As I said you cannot without a Mac, you may want to look at some of the solutions here https://learnappmaking.com/develop-ios-apps-on-windows-pc/